# Were Osama Bin Laden's family members flown out of the United States after the 9/11 attacks, during a time when there was a ban on air travel?

Tags: 9-11, osama-bin-laden

In the documentary, Fahrenheit 911, it is said that Osama Bin Laden's family members were flown out of the United States just days after the 9/11 terrorist attacks, and during a time when there was a ban on all air travel.

Is this true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They were flown out, but not when air travel was banned.

Firstly, civilian air traffic was [allowed to resume](http://www.cnn.com/2001/TRAVEL/NEWS/09/13/faa.airports/) "at 11 a.m. EDT [eastern daylight time] Thursday [13 September 2001]", so there was only about a 48 hour period where flights were prohibited.

As explained in a 30 September 2001 New York Times [article](http://www.nytimes.com/2001/09/30/world/a-nation-challenged-the-family-fearing-harm-bin-laden-kin-fled-from-us.html):

> Both planes, one jumbo jet carrying 100 family members, and the other 40, were eventually allowed to leave when airports reopened and passports were checked

...

> The young members of the bin Laden clan were driven or flown under F.B.I. supervision to a secret assembly point in Texas and then to Washington from where they left the country on a private charter plane when airports reopened three days after the attacks.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to DavePhD's answer, a little digging shows that Richard Clarke, the Chief of Counterterrorism at the time, took sole responsibility for approving the flights:

> Moore, on his website and in The Official Fahrenheit 9/11 Reader, 
>   points to additional statements by Richard Clarke, also published in 
>   The Hill, which he believes support his contention that the White 
>   House approved the flights.[31] The following is a chronological 
>   summary:

September 3, 2003:

> In his testimony before the Senate Judiciary
>   Committee's Subcommittee on Terrorism, Clarke said: "It is true that
>   members of the bin Laden family were among those who left. We knew
>   that at the time. I can't say much more in open session, but it was a
>   conscious decision with complete review at the highest levels of the
>   State Department and the FBI and the White House."[32]

March 24, 2004:

> In testimony to the 9/11 Commission, Clarke indicated that the request
>   was not abnormal, "The Saudi embassy, therefore, asked for these
>   people to be evacuated; the same sort of thing that we do all the time
>   in similar crises, evacuating Americans. The request came to me and I
>   refused to approve it." He goes on to explain that the FBI eventually
>   approved the flights and he describes conversations in which the FBI
>   has said that there was no one who left on those flights who the FBI
>   now wants to interview.

March 24, 2004:

> "I would love to be able to
>   tell you who did it, who brought this proposal to me, but I don't
>   know. The two – since you press me, the two possibilities that are
>   most likely are either the Department of State or the White House
>   Chief of Staff's Office. But I don't know."

May 25, 2004:

> In an
>   interview with The Hill newspaper, published the following day, Clarke
>   said: "I take responsibility for it. I don't think it was a mistake,
>   and I'd do it again." He went on to say that "It didn't get any higher
>   than me... On 9–11, 9–12 and 9–13, many things didn't get any higher
>   than me. I decided it in consultation with the FBI."

Here's the source:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fahrenheit_9/11_controversies